# Why does my UseState hook keeps on failing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to use **UseState** hook for updating data in my `Table` component. The data to be used in the `Table` component is fetched by another function which is imported `paginationForDataAdded`.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple errors in the console, but you only read the last one. Please show the previous error.

Comment: Would you kindly comment in the code snippet, to guide us on which line exactly is triggering the error? Thanks

Comment: The page just goes complete  blank and in the console it just mentions The above error occurred in the Table component: in...... a whole set of files which I am working with

Comment: I mentioned the line. When I try to update the state.

Comment: Am interested in this prop within the Table, `data={searchResults.resultarray || []}`, kindly mention the initial state of `searchResults` and where is `resultarray` introduced initially?

Comment: If `paginationForDataAdded` is returning an object with different properties, how is that a functional component? That does not look like a component at all - is that a hook or just a simple function?

Comment: @goto1 So sorry my bad it's just a function

Comment: @MwamiTovi It comes in from the imported paginationForDataAdded function. when I use data={searchResults.resultarray || []} everything works fine. The moment I try to update state error comes

Comment: Is the code that uses `paginationForDataAdded` and the `useState` hook the one that renders the `Table` component?

Comment: @goto1 yes the code which I quoted is the same that renders the table component

Comment: And is `paginationForDataAdded` an API call or just a synchronous call?

Comment: I guess it's an API call because it fetches data from another search service

Comment: Do you know what that actually looks like?

Comment: It's apretty large file with reducers, async functions etc etc.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what this function actually returns... It is a `Promise` or just a function that returns an `object` - solutions will differ.

Comment: So initially, `allData` is an empty array, and later (after the data fetch), it's updated to `searchResults`. So probably our focus should be on this, where are you using this `allData`?

Comment: @MwamiTovi I want to use this in my Table component. The issue is when I'm trying to set the state of **allData** by `setAllData(searchResults)` error arises.

Comment: @goto1 I'm guessing it's a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `paginationForDataAdded` is a function that returns a `Promise` which resolves with an object that looks like the following:

```js
{ 
  searchResults: { resultarray: [...] }, 
  furnishedData: [...], 
  entitledData: [...] 
}
```

You should do the following your in component:

```js
function App(props) {
  const [allData, setAllData] = React.useState([]);
  // ...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    paginationForDataAdded({
      searchFunction: search,
      collectionsData: collections,
    })
    .then(
      ({ searchResults, furnishedData, entitledData }) => {
        const nextAllData = searchResults.resultarray || [];
        setAllData(nextAllData);
      }
    )
    .catch(/* handle errors appropriately */);

    // an empty dependency array so that this hooks runs
    // only once when the component renders for the first time
  }, [])

  return (
    <Table 
      id="pop-table"
      data={allData}
      tableColumns={[...]}
    />
  );
}
```

---

However, if `paginationForDataAdded` is not an asynchronous call, then you should do the following:

```js
function App(props) {
  const [allData, setAllData] = React.useState([]);
  // ...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const {
      searchResults,
      furnishedData,
      entitledData,
    } = paginationForDataAdded({
      searchFunction: search,
      collectionsData: collections
    });
    const nextAllData = searchResults.resultarray || [];
    setAllData(nextAllData)

    // an empty dependency array so that this hooks runs
    // only once when the component renders for the first time
  }, [])

  return (
    <Table 
      id="pop-table"
      data={allData}
      tableColumns={[...]}
    />
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Its look like stackoverflow due to re-rendering.
`setAllData(searchResults);` will re-render the component and again make api call and repated.

right way to call API.

```
 const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);

useEffect(function () {
  const {
    searchResults,
    furnishedData,
    entitledData
  } = paginationForDataAdded({
    searchFunction: search,
    collectionsData: collections
  });
  setAllData(searchResults);
});
```

Comment: The way you're using the `useEffect` hook does not look correct at all...

Comment: React Hook "paginationForDataAdded" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: @goto1 my bad. Corrected

Comment: @BrattyNeal you are using useState.So, its functional component.

Comment: Assuming `paginationForDataAdded` is a hook, this is still incorrect, and it should be used outside of `useEffect` and then you'd specify `searchResults` in a dependency array to update the `allData` state. Right now, this will get called after every re-render.

Comment: @goto1 Exactly otherwise all my other fields inside useEffect comes as undefined

Comment: @BrattyNeal please share complete component.Let me correct

Comment: It's the same as the code I have quoted. The return method for my Table component is exactly the same

Comment: only the function which having code setAllData() call and api call